# Google People API - ordering by the update time not working as expected

Tags: java, google-people-api

I've been successfully using Google People API for retrieving my Google contacts, but I've discovered that API does not sort correctly by the last update time (eg. using `setSortOrder("LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING")`). What's more, it turns out that there is an interesting pattern when looking at the output of this code:

```java
  private static void getLastModified() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    PeopleService service = getService();
    ListConnectionsResponse response =
        service.people().connections().list("people/me")
        .setPageSize(30)
        .setPersonFields("names,metadata")
        .setSortOrder("LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING")
        .execute();
    for (Person person : response.getConnections()) {
      //System.out.println(person.getNames());
      for (Source s : person.getMetadata().getSources()) {
        if (s.getType().equals("CONTACT")) {
          System.out.println(s.getUpdateTime());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Results with LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING sorting order:

```
2020-05-07T19:27:27.469Z    <-- ok (which means this contact is for sure modified by me on the given day)
2020-05-07T19:27:03.418Z    <-- ok
2020-05-07T19:26:20.219Z    <-- ok
2020-05-07T19:25:39.684Z    <-- ok
2020-05-07T19:25:13.823Z    <-- ok
2020-05-07T19:24:13.732Z    <-- ok
2020-05-07T13:04:47.637Z    <-- ok
2020-04-12T17:18:31.714156Z <-- NOT ok (contact is probably modified by me on that day, but why is it positioned incorrectly?)
2020-04-15T20:49:28.733412Z <-- NOT ok
2020-05-06T17:20:19.840Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T17:18:22.134Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T17:17:33.185Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T16:41:00.368Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T16:40:50.119Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T15:02:49.218Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:29:27.963Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:28:40.890Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:26:56.322Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:26:04.658Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:25:17.177Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:24:12.801Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:23:13.461Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T14:22:04.888Z    <-- ok
2020-04-12T19:26:25.392253Z <-- NOT ok
2020-05-06T12:05:32.209Z    <-- ok
2020-05-06T11:57:11.286Z    <-- ok
2018-08-15T13:49:04.254001Z <-- NOT ok
2020-04-12T15:10:27.421184Z <-- NOT ok
2020-05-05T17:51:52.572Z    <-- ok
2020-05-05T17:50:43.904Z    <-- ok
```

After analysing this further, it looks like all misplaced contacts have two types of `source` object in their `metadata` structure (`CONTACT` and `PROFILE`) of which only `CONTACT` contains the `updateTime` timestamp but API obviously takes into the account the other one - the `PROFILE` timestamp that is NOT visible via API.
In other words, misplaced contacts from my list are probably not misplaced, they are rather changed from their original owner, but the API doesn't reveal this second timestamp.

Can someone shed some more light on this and suggest how to force API to ignore the `PROFILE` metadata source and sort only according to my modification timestamps?

Comment: To my understanding this is intended behavior, the important is the last time the person was modified. If you still think this is a bug you could go ahead and try to post it in [`Google Issue Tracker`](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). Regarding your question, could you fit all your contacts in memory? I don't see how would you sort them yourself otherwise, you are limited by the way google is delivering your information.

Comment: @Raserhin Yes, I can fit all my contacts in memory or in database (Google provides a way of retrieving subsequent pages via submitting pageToken received in the previous request) and do all the sorting there.I agree that everything described above is probably intended behaviour but then they should have made the correct last modification time available through API.

Comment: So, can you order the list after retrieving all the contacts? I understood that you do have all the information to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the @Raserhin for the suggestion to post the issue to Google Issue Tracker - I did that, got an answer and I am able to answer my own question.

As for the first part of the question:

> Can someone shed some more light on this ...?

At https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156048409 I got a detailed explanation which proved my speculations:

> Our backend service does the sorting based on the last modified timestamp from both contacts and profiles contained in a given merged person. However when our People service passes through the data, it only exposes the timestamp from contacts, not from profiles. Yes, it is not an informative API design, when the sorting key fields are not fully returned. But I need to run the idea within the team and privacy review, if we want to expose the profile change timestamp.

Second part of the question:

> how to force API to ignore the `PROFILE` metadata source and sort only according to my modification timestamps?

API obviously can't do that at the moment so each developer who needs to use this type of sorting will have to take described behaviour into account and choose either to accept it or create a workaround (eg. retrieve all the contacts and sort them in place if it's not too expensive).

Answer (score 0):

Today, we can order by:

- LAST_MODIFIED_ASCENDING  : Sort people by when they were changed; older
  entries first.
- LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING  : Sort people by when they were
  changed; newer entries first.
- FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING  : Sort people by
  first name.
- LAST_NAME_ASCENDING   : Sort people by last name.

Source : https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#sortorder

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/ReadSourceType#ENUM_VALUES.READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT) is what you looking for:

> READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT  Returns SourceType.CONTACT

That is the answer on your question: *"how to force API to ignore the PROFILE metadata source and sort only according to my modification timestamps?*"